# Pasting Phone number from Outlook to JavaFX TextField or TextArea produce Extraneous Characters

Tags: java, javafx, outlook, textarea, textfield

I'm having a strange issue where if a user copies and pastes a phone number from Outlook Contacts to a text field or text area in javaFX, a bunch of extraneous characters are coming over with it.

For example, if they copy "(555) 555-1234" from the Outlook Contact field and paste in the javaFX app text field or area, the result is *"(555) 555-1234e.UX.FlexClipboard.FUpdateAcbUi", "CV": "ER1soZ/YLEibq7jkbdMVCg.163", "ProcessIdentifier": "OUTLOOK.exe_16.0.13029.20308_X86_{A16C1D11-D89F-482C-9BAB-B8E46DD3150A}"} "Activity.CV": "ER1soZ/YLEibq7jkbdMVCg.162", "Activity.Duration": 86, "Ac"*

- This only seems to happen from phone number fields in Outlook. Other fields - name, address, etc. seem to work fine.
- If i paste from Outlook to Word, a text file, even a file in intelliJ, it comes across normally
- it doesn't matter if I copy or paste via Ctrl-V or right mouse selection or even programmatically

Sorry - there really is no 'code' to show here. I believe it will happen with any FX app text field or area.

Ideas?

Comment: _I believe it will happen with any FX app text field or area_ then write a very simple app with just a single textArea ..

Comment: Do you have any fx apps with a text field? do you have Outlook? if so, copy a phone number from outlook and paste in the FX app. No need for me to write anything for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to just check if the string contains too many characters then remove them.
it's quick and easy but it's not the most efficient way

```
private static String checkString(String s ){

    if (s.length() > 12){

        for(int i =0; i< s.length(); i++){
            if(s.charAt(i) > 'a' && s.charAt(i) < 'z'){
            return s.substring(0, i);
            }
        }

    }
    return s;
}
```